# JAXB in maven multi module

Tags: maven, module, jaxb

I am having a weird problem with JAXB in my maven multi-module project.
One of my components creates BPMN 2.0 XML using JAXB. Did not create the classes myself but rather used

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.ow2.orchestra.designer</groupId>
   <artifactId>bpmn-jaxb-model</artifactId>
   <version>4.9.0</version>
   <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Tests in that module all run fine and I can see the created XML file and its content.

A second module represents the prototype WebFrontend.
It has the first component as a dependency and uses it.

If I then call the method that creates the BPMN 2.0 XML from the WebFrontend,
I get a JAXBException as seen below:

```
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "org.ow2.orchestra.jaxb.bpmn" doesnt contain    ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:186)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    ...
```

How can it be that it JAXB works fine in one maven module but not when that module is used somewhere else?

Can anyone give me pointers?

EDIT: When I look into at the dependencies in Netbeans I clearly see ObjectFactory.class in the right package in the right jar... 
Is this maybe some freaky Jetty problem?

Comment: Seems like dependency is missing in the web app. Try `mvn dependency:tree', maybe this would shed some light.

Answer (score 0):

These types of problems usually end up being version conflicts... do a mvn dependency:tree on each module and compare the dependencies.

If you don't see any discrepancies, load the modules one at a time in Eclipse, do a <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and type in the class name. Can you load the same class from different jars? how about if all the modules are open?

Comment: The dependencies are equal in both modules. I am that maybe something does not get pulled into the JAR at the point of packaging it...

Answer (score 0):

I sort of got this problem solved.
I declared the dependency as 'provided' in the first module and added it to the jetty dependencies in the pom.xml of the WebApp. I don't really like it but as I am running out of time this is the best fix I can currently get.